# CodeLLDB does not react and throw any errors

Tags: codelldb

This is my launch.json file

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "LLDB",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/chibicc",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

[Picture of Vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCJxM.png)
Simply after launch the debugger nothing appears in the variables section.
Errors are not given, how can I fix this problem?

I have tried it on another simple "hello world" program and it still did not work